# NestJS: 404 Not Found Error on existing route

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I'm getting a 404 Error if I POST to an existing route of my NestJS application. 
The strange thing is, that the request works fine if validation fails.

I.e. a POST request to my route with an empty body or missing data in the body returns:

```
{
    "error": "Validation failed",
    "validationErrors": {
        "email": [
            "Email can't be blank"
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

And a request with all required data returns a 404 Error.

**The error stacktrace:**

```
{ Error: [object Object]
    at callback (/Users/matthias/Dev/Git/sf-nest-server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/routes-resolver.js:43:19)
    at /Users/matthias/Dev/Git/sf-nest-server/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:8:23
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/matthias/Dev/Git/sf-nest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/matthias/Dev/Git/sf-nest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/matthias/Dev/Git/sf-nest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/matthias/Dev/Git/sf-nest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at Immediate.next (/Users/matthias/Dev/Git/sf-nest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/matthias/Dev/Git/sf-nest-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15)
    at runCallback (timers.js:796:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:729:5)
```

**app.ts**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ErrorFilter } from './errors/error.filter';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as Superlogin from 'superlogin';

import * as usersSuperloginConfig from '@config/superlogin-users';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();

  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').load();
  }
  const usersSuperlogin = new Superlogin(usersSuperloginConfig);
  app.use('/users/auth', usersSuperlogin.router);

  usersSuperlogin.on('signup', (userDoc, provider) => {
    Logger.log(userDoc);

  });

  app.setViewEngine('ejs');
  app.useGlobalFilters(new ErrorFilter());
  app.setBaseViewsDir(__dirname + '/views');

  await app.listen(process.env.PORT);
  Logger.log(`Listening on Port ${process.env.PORT}`);
}

bootstrap();
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you add your relevant controller and service methods?

Comment: Just added the code of my app.ts where I bind my app to the Superlogin routes.